# User is not Redirected after wallet authentication using NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, blockchain, web3js, web3modal

I'm trying to redirect the user to `onboard` page when he successfully connects to his wallet. Web3Button is not returning anything.

How to do that? I'm stuck here.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

import { Web3Button } from "@web3modal/react";
import { useProvider } from "wagmi";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Hero = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const provider = useProvider();

  const handleConnect = async () => {
    try {
      if (provider) {
        router.push("/onboard");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <main className="container mx-auto">
      <div className="flex flex-col flex-wrap items-center space-y-6 justify-center h-[70vh]">
        <h2 className="text-2xl px-4 text-center md:text-4xl sm:text-3xl lg:text-5xl font-bold ">
         Title
        </h2>
        <p className="px-4 text-center text-md md:text-xl lg:text-2xl">
         Description
        </p>
        <Web3Button />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are connected to metamask when you get the accounts from metamask with

```
const accounts = (await ethereum?.request({
      method: "eth_requestAccounts",
    })) as string[];
```

if you get accounts that means you are connected

```
if(accounts){
   router.push("/whatever")
}
```

But I dont think that connected to metamask is enough, you should also add logic to see if connected network is correct network and then you should redirect the user